# Trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF - not sure what's causing this

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger, nocount

I'm running into an intermittent error with a SQL Server trigger that has me stumped, because it seems like I'm doing all of the right things to prevent the error from occurring. The error I'm getting is "A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF while another outstanding result set was active." I've done web searches and found some things that I applied to my trigger that I thought would resolve the issue, but it does not seem to have done so. This is an issue that happens infrequently, but enough to be a problem. I haven't been able to tell why this is happening, though. Here's an example of what this trigger looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAppointmentLogDispatch] ON [dbo].[Appointment] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO DispatchQueue (ObjectType, CompanyID, KeyField1, KeyField2, KeyField3, KeyField4, KeyField5, Deleted, DateChanged)
        SELECT 'Appointment', ISNULL(i.CompanyID, 0), ISNULL(i.OrderID, -1), ISNULL(i.AppointmentID, -1), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, GETUTCDATE()
        FROM inserted i
            LEFT JOIN deleted d
                ON i.AppointmentID = d.AppointmentID
        WHERE ISNULL(i.Field1, '') <> ISNULL(d.Field1, '')
            OR ISNULL(i.Field2, '') <> ISNULL(d.Field2, '')
            OR ISNULL(i.Field3, 0) <> ISNULL(d.Field3, 0)
            OR ISNULL(i.Field4, '1/1/2000') <> ISNULL(d.Field4, '1/1/2000')
            OR ISNULL(i.Field5, '1/1/2000') <> ISNULL(d.Field5, '1/1/2000')
            OR ISNULL(i.Field6, 0) <> ISNULL(d.Field6, 0)
            OR ISNULL(i.Field7, '') <> ISNULL(d.Field7, '')
            OR ISNULL(i.Field8, '') <> ISNULL(d.Field8, '')
    END ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO DispatchQueue (ObjectType, CompanyID, KeyField1, KeyField2, KeyField3, KeyField4, KeyField5, Deleted, DateChanged)
        SELECT 'Appointment', ISNULL(CompanyID, 0), ISNULL(OrderID, -1), ISNULL(AppointmentID, -1), NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, GETUTCDATE()
        FROM deleted
    END
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

All the trigger is doing is listening for changes to a set of fields on a table named Appointment (or for a deletion of a record in this table). If there is a deletion or changes to the fields that are being checked in the WHERE clause, it inserts a new record into a DispatchQueue table, which is used by a separate process that isn't relevant to the issue here.

When searching for solutions to this issue before, the general consensus that I came to that sounded like it would resolve the issue would be to add the SET NOCOUNT ON command to the beginning of my trigger and to add the SET NOCOUNT OFF command to the last line of my trigger. That didn't work in this case though, so I'm stumped about where to look next.

Would removing the SET NOCOUNT OFF command at the end fix the issue? I'm wondering if it might, because in a SQL Trace that showed that the issue was occurring, the error was reported right after the SET NOCOUNT OFF statement was run. If so, would that introduce any other potential issues? It doesn't seem like my trigger is returning a Resultset (its just running an EXISTS statement to check and see if I'm dealing with an insertion or a deletion and then its running an INSERT statement to insert data into another table), but could it potentially be doing that somewhere (or in some way) that I'm not seeing or understanding?

Could something else happening in the database outside of my trigger be causing this issue to be reported when it runs?

I appreciate any and all insight. Please let me know if I can provide any further information on this.

Comment: Weird trigger errors often happen because of... other weird triggers running. If you have one trigger you probably have others. So first question is: is there a trigger on `DispatchQueue` ?

Comment: Why don't you start with **testing** to remove that last line? `SET NOCOUNT ON` specifies that SQL Server won't report the number of affected records to "the outside" when the procedure/trigger has run. If you set that option `OFF` again before the routine is left, that number *IS* reported. Yes, I'm pretty sure that removing that statement will fix the issue.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid There are no triggers on DispatchQueue, but there are other triggers on the Appointment table. The trigger I worked on is part of an integration with another company's software system, so most of the triggers in the database are unfortunately not something that I can touch and I have limited knowledge of them. So if something is interfering with my trigger in another trigger, it would be difficult to figure out where the problem is occurring. I'm just trying to make sure that my own triggers are as error proof as possible.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Thanks for the feedback. I will try removing the SET NOCOUNT OFF line. I didn't make it clear in my original post, but this is difficult to test because I am not able to replicate this issue on local development databases. This is just happening on a specific customer database that has live data that I can't do much in the way of debugging against, so I'm just trying to be careful in this case. I was just wondering if there was a glaring problem in my trigger that may have caused this.

Comment: There is no glaring problem in your trigger (though I would suggest using ISO date literals or explicitly casting). If there are other triggers on the Appointment table then be aware there is no guaranteed order of execution. How many triggers are on Appointment? It's really a difficult one if the error is intermittent and only on a prod database. Do you have access to the source on the other Appointment triggers? I would inspect those for the issue

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback @Nick.McDermaid. There are four other triggers on the Appointment table that are not our own. We do have access to the source of the other triggers and are currently setting up a time to review them with our integration partner (as they are the ones that understand those particular triggers better)

Comment: I guess the non determinant nature of the execution order for the five triggers on `Appointment` are contributing to the intermittent nature of the error.